# Calculate grouped average using activerecord/pgsql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a simple `comments` table:

```
id    post_id
=======================
1     'a11'
2     'a11'
3     'b22'
4     'b22'
5     'b22'
```

I'm calculating the average comments per post:

```
comment_counts = Comment.group(:post_id).count.values
avg = comment_counts.sum / comment_counts.size.to_f
# => 2.5
```

I'd prefer to let DB handle the calculation. How can I achieve this using only activerecord/sql?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a very ActiveRecord-ish way of doing this, but can offer the following:

```
Comment(:post_id).select("avg(count(*)) over () avg").take.avg
```

... which returns a BigDecimal, or the probably more efficient:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select avg(c_star) from (select count(*) c_star from comments group by post_id) t").first["avg"].to_d
```

It occurs to me, though, that this doesn't take into account the Posts that received no Comments.